# Multi Hop SSHing using RequestTTY Method

Tags: ssh, proxy, configuration

I tried to map the following multi hop using a ssh configuration file:

`ssh -tt -l jumphost 192.168.1.5 ssh -tt -l jumphost 192.168.2.111 ssh -tt -l inside_server 192.168.3.50`

without using one of the following commands as a config:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -q -oProxyCommand=\"ssh -q jumphost@192.168.1.5 nc -q0 192.168.2.111 22\" jumphost@192.168.2.111 nc -q0 192.168.3.50 22" inside_server@192.168.3.50
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -oProxyCommand=\"ssh -W %%h:%%p jumphost@192.168.1.5\" jumphost@192.168.2.111" inside_server@192.168.3.50
ssh -J jumphost@192.168.1.5,jumphost@192.168.2.111 inside_server@192.168.3.50
```

Using the following ssh config

```
cat ~/.ssh/config
Host jump
   RequestTTY force
   Hostname 192.168.1.5
   User jumphost

Host inside_gateway
   ProxyCommand ssh jump
   RequestTTY force
   Hostname 192.168.2.111
   User jumphost

Host inside_inside_server
   ProxyCommand ssh inside_gateway
   RequestTTY force
   Hostname 192.168.3.50
   User inside_server
```

I get a first login but after that it fails:

```
ssh inside_inside_server -vvv
OpenSSH_8.9 ... OpenSSL 3.0 ...
... 
jumphost@192.168.1.5's password:
Bad packet length 21...
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: message authentication code    
incorrect
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `ProxyJump` instead of `ProxyCommand`. If you goal is to simplify this command line:

```
ssh -tt -l jumphost 192.168.1.5 \
  ssh -tt -l jumphost 192.168.2.111 \
  ssh -tt -l inside_server 192.168.3.50
```

You would want a configuration something like this:

```
Host jump
  Hostname 192.168.1.5
  User jumphost

Host inside_gateway 
  Hostname 192.168.2.111
  ProxyJump jump
  User jumphost

Host inside_inside_server
  Hostname 192.168.3.50
  ProxyJump inside_gateway
  User inside_server
```

When you run `ssh inside_inside_server`, this will:

1. Establish a connection from your local host to `jump`
2. Overlay on connection 1 a connection from your local host to `inside_gateway`
3. Overlay on connection 2 a connection from your local host to `inside_inside_server`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With `ProxyJump` it would be like: `ssh -J jumphost@192.168.1.5,jumphost@192.168.2.111 inside_server@192.168.3.50`. Isn't there a possibilty to do it like `ssh -tt -l jumphost 192.168.1.5 ssh -tt -l jumphost 192.168.2.111 ssh -tt -l inside_server 192.168.3.50` in the `ssh_config`? 
My goal is to understand how far `ssh` as called from the terminal can be mapped to `ssh_config` at this point.